# How to move any 2 robots simultaneously in gazebo?

Tags: ros, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to put any 2 robots in gazebo and keep them moving simultaneously in a fixed square path. I wanted to know which robot should I use and how should I command them to move? I am using ROS-Indigo with Gazebo-2.2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236862/how-to-move-any-2-robots-simultaneously-in-gazebo?/) by [Pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22900/pikachu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. If Your robot models and names are same, you need to cover in a namespace each of them. As far as I know, There is no tutorial exists for converting any robot's packege to namespaced one in `indigo`. I'll write later. But You can start by following [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/236625/how-do-i-control-2-pr2-robots-in-gazebo-at-the-same-time/?answer=236631#post-id-236631) answer.
2. If their models aren't same, Directly start from this 2nd section. *(But I don't think so. Because everyone is naming topics  by same way.)* Just publish to their own velocity topics simultaneously. or You can use their own `move_base` topics to do it.

After following stages in the link above, You must create launch files before section 2 above. You need one gazebo process, sample launch file, `world.launch`;

```
<launch>
  <arg name="world"  default="milvus_repo"/>  
  <arg name="world_path" default="$(find mrp2_gazebo)/worlds/"/>             
  <arg name="gui" default="true"/>
  <arg name="debug" default="false"/>
  <arg name="paused" default="false"/>
  <env name="GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH" value="$(find mrp2_gazebo)/models:$(optenv GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH)" />

  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(arg world_path)$(arg world).world"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="$(arg debug)"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
  </include>
</launch>
```

Then start one of the robots with its namespace via `robot1.launch`;

```
<launch>
    <arg name="robot_name" default="robot1" />
    <group ns="$(arg robot_name)">
        <include file="$(find mrp2_gazebo)/launch/include/single_mrp2.launch" >
            <arg name="init_pose" value="-x 3.0 -y 0.0 -z 0.0 -R 0.0 -P 0.0 -Y 0.0" />
            <arg name="robot_name" value="$(arg robot_name)" />
        </include>
        <include file="$(find mrp2_control)/launch/controls.launch" >
            <arg name="robot_name" value="$(arg robot_name)" />
            <arg name="sim" value="true" />
        </include>
    </group>
</launch>
```

`single_mrp2.launch` contains `mrp2.launch` and some teleop and diagnostic launches. If you have a running robot without namespace, you probably have these ones. (And if you will use these ones in first try, some remapping operations may be needed in inside of them). `mrp2.launch` file:

```
<launch>
    <arg name="robot"  default="full"/>
    <arg name="gzpose" default=""/>
    <arg name="robot_name" default="robot1"/>
    <!-- PARSE ROBOT MODEL -->
    <include file="$(find mrp2_description)/launch/description.launch" >
        <arg name="robot" value="$(arg robot)"/>
        <arg name="robot_name" value="$(arg robot_name)"/>
    </include>
    <!-- SPAWN IN GAZEBO -->
    <node pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" name="$(anon spawn_model)"
          args="-urdf -param robot_description $(arg gzpose) -model mrp2_$(arg robot_name)" />
    <remap from="odom" to="$(arg robot_name)/odom"/>
</launch>
```

Finally, here is the description file, also be sure the joints and frames are different, (You must edit your urdf files for this) `description.launch`;

```
<launch>
    <arg name="config" default="base" />
    <arg name="robot" default="full" />
    <arg name="robot_name" default="robot1"/>
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find mrp2_description)/robots/mrp2_$(arg robot).urdf.xacro' robot_name:=$(arg robot_name)" />
    <node name="robot_state_publisher_$(arg robot_name)" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher">
        <param name="use_tf_static" value="true"/>
        <remap from="/joint_states" to="/$(arg robot_name)/joint_states" />
    </node>
</launch>
```

After following steps carefully, and after remapping some topics like  this: `<remap from="odom" to="$(arg robot_name)/odom"/>`, Do same steps for each robot. (Just change robot name from `robot1` to `robot2` or may be `optimus_prime`) Your robots will move simultaneously.

---

Originally posted by [Orhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25268/orhan/) with karma: 856 on 2016-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pikachu](https://answers.ros.org/users/22900/pikachu/) on 2016-06-17**:
Thanks ! It really helped. :)